# Angular2 give error Argument of type 'ElementRef' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ViewContainerRef'

Tags: typescript, angular

I'm creating angular2 app using angular-cli, but when i use constructor below it will give error like this

**Error**

```
Argument of type 'ElementRef' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ViewContainerRef'. Property 'element' is missing in type 'ElementRef'.
```

my constructor is

```
constructor( _elementRef: ElementRef, _loader: DynamicComponentLoader,_parentRouter: Router, @Attribute('name') nameAttr: string,  private userService: LoginComponent) 
{
    super( _elementRef, _loader, _parentRouter, nameAttr);

    this.parentRouter = _parentRouter;
    this.publicRoutes = ['', 'login', 'signup'];
}
```

what is wrong with my code?. i'm using angular2 rc.3

Comment: How this class is constructed?

Comment: You construct or you let this for Angular DI?

Comment: I got this from blog about authentication.

Comment: My doubt is: you manually instantiate this class or it's a component instantiated by Angular? Because the error says you trying to assign a variable  'ElementRef' that coludn't be assigned by 'ViewContainerRef' type.

Comment: ElementRef is imported and then i have use it i'dont create it.

Comment: Ok, so Angular instatiate this component for you, the problem I think is super call, could you please provide more detail?

Comment: what info you need?.

Comment: The super class info, because there's a problem calling the super constructor. I think the parameters are in wrong order.

Comment: well I got it when we use super class constructor with 4 variable first one need to be ViewComponentRef soo I need to use ViewComponentRef

Comment: and thanks @ReginaldoCamargoRibeiro for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Add ViewContainerRef to import as well as the constructor and then use it where you were using elementRef.

Apparently this has changed recently and now you cannot pass elementRef to ViewContainerRef.

```
import {Component, DynamicComponentLoader, ElementRef, ViewContainerRef} from '@angular/core';

....

constructor( _elementRef: ElementRef, _viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef, _loader: DynamicComponentLoader, ...) 
{
    super(_viewContainerRef, _loader, ...);
}
```